# Find the $d$ such $(d^2+d)x^2-y^2=d^2-1$ has postive integer $(x,y)$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, pell-type-equations

Find all the positive integers $d$ such that
$$(d^2+d)x^2-y^2=d^2-1$$ has a positive integer solution $(x,y)$.

maybe use Pell equation some result
$$x^2-Dy^2=C$$ to solve it?

Comment: For $d=3,8,15,24,\ldots, m^2-1,\ldots$, there is a positive integer solution $(x,y)=(1,\sqrt{d+1})$.

Comment: Thanks,@HagenvonEitzen,how to prove only this solution?

Comment: Well, the question, as it is stated as a question wants to find (one, as stated) $d$ such that there is a solution. Above, we have a large list of "good $d$ values". Please edit the question, so that it reflects what is wanted **before** people start investing some effort. "Find all integers $d\in\Bbb Z$ such that there exist positive integers $x,y$ with the given property" is a different question. Please add this to the OP, if this is the question. And as it is always the case on this site: **Show own effort**. Just providing a bounty is not enough.

Comment: I don't know if a cheat will help provide insight. Wolfram Alpha offers [three solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28d%5E2%2Bd%29x%5E2-y%5E2%3Dd%5E2-1%2C+d%3E0%2C+x%3E0%2C+y%3E0++over+integers)

Answer (score 0):

This equation is just a good example of how in the Pell equations - one group of solutions-leads to the following solutions.

Let's write the equation like this. $$y^2=(d^2+d)x^2-d^2+1$$

We will make such a replacement.  $$x \longrightarrow x+1$$

Then the equation will take this form.

$$y^2=(d^2+d)x^2+2(d^2+d)x + d+1$$

You can use a general formula of this type.
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048216__

And you can see that there are solutions when  $q^2=d+1$